# Is "he" omitted in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, subjects, subject-pronoun-drop

> Knowledge of Geology.— Practical, but limited. Tells at a glance different soils from each other. **After walks has shown me splashes upon his trousers, and told me by their colour and consistence in what part of London he had received them.**

Can I change this sentence by putting "he" between "walks" and "has"?

> After walks **(he)** has shown me splashes upon his trousers, and told me by their colour and consistence in what part of London he had received them.

Source: *A Study in Scarlet*, Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: Yes, this is an example of what is called [*diary drop* or *subject pronoun drop*](http://www.isle-linguistics.org/resources/weir2009.pdf).  We sometimes leave out the subject pronoun when writing informal short summaries or diaries (which is where the name "diary drop" comes from) and this is a great example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is omitted, but implied by the sentences before it.

Is this from a Sherlock Holmes novel? It reads like the author is profiling somebody - the previous two sentences state facts about (presumably) the same person. **He** is omitted, but as it is in a string of sentences about the same subject, you are expected to understand that they are all about the same person. For example,

**He is wearing a hat. He is eating a sandwich. He is thinking about work.**

Could also be written as:

**He is wearing a hat. Eating a sandwich. Thinking about work.**

Because they follow the first sentence which starts with **He**, that still applies.